# Use of undefined constant ’message’ - assumed '’message’' in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbie to Yii framework. Have just started to learn Yii 2.0, but I am getting the following error.

Have written the below code in controllers/SiteController.php

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
// ...existing code...
public function actionSay($message = ’Hello’)
{
return $this->render(’say’, [’message’ => $message]);
}
}
```

And have written followin code in views/ControllerID/ViewName.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<?= Html::encode($message) ?>
```

SO when I run this line in browser "http://localhost/web/index.php?r=site/say&message=Hello+World"
Getting following error

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Use of undefined constant ’message’ - assumed '’message’'
1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\controllers\SiteController.php at line 99
90919293949596979899100101    }

    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    public function actionSay($message = ’Hello’)
    {
        return $this->render('say', [’message’ => $message]);
    }
}
2. in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\controllers\SiteController.php – yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleError(8, 'Use of undefined constant ’messa...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\controller...', 99, ...) at line 99
93949596979899100101    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    public function actionSay($message = ’Hello’)
    {
        return $this->render('say', [’message’ => $message]);
    }
}
```

Can any one help me in solving this error.

Comment: You've a whole bunch of curly quotes `’` change those to regular ones `'` and don't use a Word processor to "code" with.

Comment: Yes, fixing the single quote marks solves this issue.

Answer (score -1):

REPLACE: return $this->render(’say’, [’message’ => $message]); WITH: return $this->render('say', ['message' => $message]);